# Word meaning a piece of fiction about a work of art

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm seeking a single English word I recently learned (and then promptly forgot!) --a specialized technical term meaning fictional writing focused around the depiction of another work of art (*e.g.* a painting, piece of music or a play).

Example:  Walter Moers' ______ book *The Labyrinth of Dreaming Books* really strongly evoked the sensation of sitting in a theater, watching a play.

This is a real English word, but not one in common general use --you would expect it in an academic context, or to be used by a professional critic.

Comment: __descriptive__

Comment: Ode to, nod to, homage (French loanword now incorporated into English), or their more pejorative cousins, like rip-off, etc?

Comment: No, this is a technical term.  I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ekphrasis
as in "*The Picture of Dorian Gray* is an ekphrastic novel."

Comment: Thank you!  It proved to be hard to search, and the closest thing I could think of was "eidetic" which is not quite the same.

Comment: You learn something new every day. I was unable to figure this out by searching and was so curious that I was refreshing the page every couple of minutes until this answer appeared.

Comment: Hi Yubei Tang, welcome to ELU StackExchange! Thank you for answering the question. Please [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/468836/edit) to include an explanation, context, and supporting facts. you can offer evidence, such as the definition from a good online dictionary, or contrast your answer with other answers. Whatever will make this the “right” answer. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. Kindly see: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers)”.

Comment: What's the definition?